# What would be a test case for this method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to development and I'm trying to improve the test coverage for my project. This is one of the methods for which I'm trying to add unit cases, however I'm not able to come up with a valid test case for this method as all the method does is assign a value to a variable based on logical conditions.

```
Object getValue(boolean isEven, list<String> stringList){
    Object obj = new Object();
    if((isEven && stringList.contains("C") || (!isEven && stringList.contains("D")))
        obj.setResult("result_CorD");
    else
        obj.setResult("anythingElse");
    }
return obj;
}
```

What would be the recommended test case  in such a situation?

Comment: Get the result object and assert it.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 4 test cases or 1 test with 4 different inputs

one way of writing such test would be:

```
Assert.assertEquals("result_CorD", getValue(true, listWithC).getResult());
Assert.assertEquals("anythingElse", getValue(true, listWithoutC).getResult());
Assert.assertEquals("result_CorD", getValue(false, listWithD).getResult());
Assert.assertEquals("anythingElse", getValue(false, listWithoutD).getResult());
```